# Classic asp sql query returns only part of result

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am trying to fix a bug on a server that has been moved from a local server to Amazon servers recently. Since the move we have experienced this problem:
A dropdown showing a list of rows from a table in the database only shows about one third of the rows (compared to if i run the query directly on the server). Also when you select a result from the query more stuff will happen. Nothing happens.

```
<select name="Producent">
 <option value="0"><%=newproduct_043%></option>
  <% 
   Set Rs = Conn.Execute("select id,name from Producent where isnull (Producentlink,0)=0 order by name")
   if not sDealer > "0" then
    set RS2 = Conn.Execute("select id from producent where name  = 'noname'")
   sDealer=cstr(RS2("ID"))
   end if
   While Not Rs.EOF
   %><option value="<%=Rs("ID")%>"<%If sDealer = cstr(Rs("ID")) Then Response.Write " Selected"%>><%=Rs("Name")%></option><%
   Rs.Movenext
  Wend
   %>
  </select>&nbsp;
```

I have activated ASP error messages, but nothing shows. I have tried activating every log I have been able to find but nothing shows any errors.

My thoughts:

- The SQL server connection goes through a ODBC System DSN on the same server. Could this be the bottleneck?
- I am no expert in classic ASP, so I might have missed something obvious.
- Did I miss some setup on the new server which limits the result shown in the ASP site?

This is kind of not my field of expertise (not the server and not classic ASP)

Comment: Check the HTML source of the page in the browser. There could have been an error but you're not seeing it in the browser because it happened in the middle of the `<select>`. (I've run into that problem before.)

Comment: Thanks. No errors though. The code just ends abruptly
`code`
...<option value="134340">(cencured name)</option><option value="134341">(censured name)</option><option value="20183
`code`

I wrote "censured name" instead of the manufacturer name, since it's probably nothing to do with them specifically. I can see that the SELECT today returns a different number of rows than it did yesterday.

Comment: I still suspect there's an error but error reporting is probably turned off, as it usually is off by default these days. In IIS go to your web site/app and then ASP > Compilation > Debugging Properties, then set *Send Errors To Browser* to True. Also, in the code, comment out any lines that say `on error resume next` because that causes errors to be ignored.

Comment: I already had the Send Errors To Browser on. There are no errors that I can see, not in the shown page or the Page Source. I can see that even though the SQL query returns a different result from time to time, it is almost the same length (4 digits difference). Can it be some SQL result max length? Or page source length on the IIS?

Comment: If you install visual studio on the Amazon VM, you can use the script debugging feature to step through your classic ASP code and look at all the details of your ADO objects. Check out http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio-2013 for details

Answer (score -1):

In ASP you have to end an `if` statement with an `end if`. In your code you are using:

```
<%If sDealer = cstr(Rs("ID")) Then Response.Write " Selected"%>
```

That should be:

```
<%If sDealer = cstr(Rs("ID")) Then Response.Write " Selected" end if%>
```

Furthermore I would place the text " Selected" in a variable and use the variable in you `OPTION` tag

Comment: Ah the code is ALOT longer than this bit, and it has been running without problems on the old server. -It's part of a HUGE legacy code part that I am the only developer to maintain.

Comment: @AlbertHugo That's not correct. In VBScript you do not need `end if` if the if..then statement is on one line.